# LALR Grammar desambiguation for function calls statements (as in Python grammar)

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, lalr

I'm trying to write a simple LALR parser for a custom DSL. My grammar looks like this :

```
main : stmts

stmts : expr stmts
      |

expr : arithmetics
     | function_call
     | VARNAME
     | INT

arithmetics : expr '+' expr
            | expr '-' expr
            | expr '*' expr
            | expr '/' expr
            | '(' expr ')'

function_call : VARNAME '(' arg_list ')'

arg_list : expr ',' arg_list
         | expr
```

I can write simple arithmetics and function calls, but I'm facing an ambiguation problem.

For instance `a (2)` could be either seen as the function `a` called with parameter `2`.
Or it could be seen as two distinct statements : first `a`, then the number `2` surrounded by parenthesis. I'm facing shift/reduce conflicts when '(' is encountered as it can be either used in arithmetics operation and to make function calls.

Here are two different ways to produce `a (2)` :

```
stmts -> expr -> function_call -> VARNAME ( arg_list ) -> VARNAME ( expr ) -> a ( 2 )

stmts -> expr stmts -> expr expr -> VARNAME arithmetics -> VARNAME ( expr ) -> a ( 2 )
```

How can I desambiguate such a grammar ?

I noticed that the Python grammar allows to write such things without ambiguity :

```
def a(x):
    return x+2

a
(5)
(2)
a
a
a
(8)
print(
a
(9)
)
```

How can I make my grammar change to make it work similarly ?
Thanks.

Comment: Nowhere in your example are you able to write `a (2)` in python and have it interpreted as anything other than a function call. There is no ambiguity. End-Of-Line is significant.

Comment: It's perfectly fine if it's interpreted as a function call. My grammar is actually ambiguous since `a(2)` can be produced both by `stmts -> expr -> function_call -> VARNAME ( arg_list ) -> VARNAME ( expr ) -> a ( 2 )` and `stmts -> expr expr -> VARNAME arithmetics -> VARNAME ( expr ) -> a ( 2 )`.

Comment: Exactly. Your grammar is ambiguous because you ignore newlines. Python's grammar is not ambiguous because it uses a newline (or semicolon) as a statement terminator. Python does not let you write two consecutive statements on the same line without a semicolon between them.

Comment: I see ... but it seems now quite complex to make newlines a mandatory symbol in some cases and ignore them elsewhere. Not even sure it is possible with LALR parsers, am i right ?

Comment: Python does it in the scanner. (The rule is simple: inside parentheses, brackets and braces, newlines and leading whitespace are ignored. Outside, the language is whitespace sensitive.)

Comment: But in my case, how could I ensure to get a mandatory newline after each statement, but allowing arbitrary newlines elsewhere. If I add a NEWLINE token which will be required like with a rule like `stmts : expr NEWLINE stmts`, all additionnal newlines would be considered as syntax errors since they wouldn't be expected by the grammar.

Comment: Yes, that gets complicated. (If I understand your question correctly.) You can look at the way it works in Javascript, where semicolons are required by the grammar but are automatically inserted in certain cases, mostly at the ends of lines, when necessary to prevent a syntax error. That's a lot more complicated than the Python solution, so you might want to consider doing it Pythonically.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I wish I could stick to a simple LALR parser for this :|

Comment: For another model, you can look at Awk. In Awk, you can't put newlines inside statements, but there is a different ambiguity because string concatenation is juxtaposition, so `a ", " b`  is a concatenation of three things. This leads to the ambiguity where `f(a)` might mean "call f with argument a" or it might mean "concatenate f and a". Awk resolves this by only recognising functions calls if the parenthesis immediately follows the function name, without a space. So `f(a)` is a call and `f (a)` is a concatenation. That's also done in the scanner.

Comment: Python uses a simple parser. But indentation rules aren't context-free, so those have to be handled before they get to the parser; that's why it's done in the scanner. At the same time, the scanner decides whether a newline is significant or not. The algorithm is described in the Python reference manual.

Comment: I think I've got the idea. What seems difficult is to be able to know whether the newline will be significant or not since the scanner has no visibility over the parser state.

Comment: Yes, that's an issue. The Python scanner duplicates a very small part of the parser's work by counting open and close parens. Another possibility, if you're using a parser generator like yacc/bison, is to trigger the scanner state change with a mid-rule action. (Remember to put the MRA *before* the parenthesis.) Unfortunately, you might have to insert MRAs in a lot of rules.